# I can not make background image HTML5

Tags: html, image, background

I have been trying to place a background image behind my text on html5 page, any suggestions for how to place it behind my text?

any help is appreciated!

[screenshot of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw887.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a part of you source code? Best is placing also link to JSFiddle (or similar service) with your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Stackoverflow has supported [live demos in questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year. There's no need to resort to a third party service like JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
<body background="images/example.jpg">
```

place this between head and body of your html doc and your text will appear visable on your background.